# removing .wrapInner() and .prepend() on window.resize function

Tags: jquery

How can I achieve the following?

```
// Resize triggers
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 480) {
        $('#menu-primary-navigation').wrapInner('<li id="menu" class="dd"><ul class="sub-menu"></ul></li>');
        $('#menu').prepend('<a href="#">Menu</a>');
    }
    if (window.innerWidth >= 480) {
        // Remove the above .wrapInner & .prepend()
    }
}) .resize();
```

**UPDATE:**

[This is what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/9fHPA/) without the resize events, but I'd like to remove the .wrapInner and .prepend code when the screen is less than 480px wide.

Comment: How do you achieve what, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 480 && !$('#menu').length) {
            $('#menu-primary-navigation').wrapInner('<li id="menu" class="dd"><ul class="sub-menu"></ul></li>');
            $('#menu').prepend('<a id="premenu" href="#">Menu</a>');
        } else if (window.innerWidth > 480 && $('#menu').length) {
            $('#menu').replaceWith($('#menu > ul').children());
            $('#premenu').remove();
        }
    }).resize();

});
```

Note I added `&& !$('#menu').length`.  This is to only add the menu if it doesn't already exist.  You can also put the second `if` as an `else`, as they are mutually exclusive. (when you change the `>= 480` to `> 480`)

Demo Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/WzweR/

Demo (full screen): http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/WzweR/embedded/result/

Also, I don't think you can end up with valid markup.  Either you are wrapping non-`li` items in a `ul`, or you are adding a `a` inside of a `ul`...  But maybe I haven't thought through what your markup looks like.  I am just guessing.  And I am assuming you are collapsing part of your menu structure if the window is too narrow.

**Update:**

After seeing your code, a couple of changes.  First I was missing a `>` in my `replaceWith($('#menu > ul').children());`.  That makes a big difference, as you don't want to pull all of the `ul`s out of context.  Second, you are adding some stuff to your links, which you need to do in your resize call:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 480 && !$('#menu').length) {
        $('#menu-primary-navigation').wrapInner('<li id="menu" class="dd"><ul class="sub-menu"></ul></li>');
        $('#menu').prepend('<a id="premenu" href="#">Menu</a>');
        $('#premenu').prepend("<span class='arrow-down'></span>"); // Dropdown Arrows
        $('#premenu').next().addClass('navhidden'); // Optional
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 480 && $('#menu').length) {
        console.log("test");
        $('#menu').replaceWith($('#menu > ul').children());
        $('#premenu').remove();
    }
}).resize();
```

You will also need to change your `.click()` handler to a `.on()` call, because your elements are being created dynamically.  When they are removed, any click handlers are removed.  If you use `.on()` you essentially attach the handler to a higher element in the DOM tree and filter on the element you want to respond:

```
$('#access').on('click', 'li.dd a', function() {
    // ... do stuff here
    // This basically says, whenever something in #access is clicked,
    // check if it is a `li.dd a` link, and if so, do this stuff
});
```

Demo Code: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/9fHPA/7/

Demo (full screen): http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/9fHPA/7/embedded/result/

Comment: Here's what I have currently – this is before the resize events: http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/9fHPA/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'll test this out and let you know if it works. The jsfiddle looks good though!

Comment: Still has some bugs with styling issues but works well. Thanks.